# bash: Running a program from the console without holding it up or line noise

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I would like to run programs (for example, opening PDFs in Evince) from my bash shell. However, when I do this the simplest way (`evince filename.pdf`), the shell doesn't let me input anything until I close Evince. Additionally, after I close Evince, I get some error messages, which I would ideally prefer not to have.

How can I structure the command to make this happen?

Comment: try as follows: evince filename.pdf &  The ampersand (&) is the key to doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start evince using the following command:

`$ evince filename.pdf &> /dev/null  &`

- `&> /dev/null` will redirect both standard errors and standard output to `/dev/null` so that you will not see warnings and errors appearing in your terminal
- the last `&` at the end of the command will start the process in a background job so that you can still work with your terminal without closing evince.